# Limit rotation range for rotation gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to implement rotation functionality for my view and I am wondering how can I limit the range of rotation which user can make. For example, I need to limit rotation to +30 degrees and -30 degrees.

Rotation in my app is working fine, here is the code below:

```
- (IBAction)handleRotateSymbols:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGFloat netRotation = 0.0;
    CGFloat rotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *) sender rotation];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (rotation + netRotation);
    sender.view.transform = transform;

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        netRotation += rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the value of `rotation + netRotation` (less than `absf(M*PI/6)`) before applying `transform`?